# Найти ключ шифрования

Tags: безопасность, шифрование, информатика

Дано:

collaboration - шифротекст, полученный в результате шифрования **методом гаммирования**

альметьевский - исходный текст

Найти:

Ключ шифрования (гамму), использованную для шифрования исходного текста.

Нужно понять как решать такие задачи на бумажке.

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Первые символы двух текстов позволяют восстановить первый символ гаммы (скорее всего опрерацией XOR). Вторые символы - второй символ гаммы. Третьи символы - третий. Я не вижу в чём затруднение в вопросе.